# removeEvents only removes events for current month

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

When I use `$('#calender).fullCalendar('removeEvents');`, this only removed events from the current month (December) and not others (november,Jan,Feb....).

How can I remove all events ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var UsrAux;        
    UsrAux=$('#name').val();                  
    $('#name').blur(function(){    
        UsrAux=$('#name').val();                        
        var source =   {
            url: 'CalendarServer.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {                            // Parms
                uno: 'Somenthing',    
                UsrCdg: UsrAux                                            
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('error!');
            },
            color: '#e2ebef',   // a non-ajax option
            textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
        };                                 
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', source);
    });  

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        draggable: true, 
        height: 400,    
        cache: true, 
        eventSources: [
        // your event source
        {
            url: 'CalendarServer.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {                            // Parms
                uno: 'something',    
                UsrCdg: $('#name').val()                                            
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('error!');
            },
            color: '#e2ebef',   // a non-ajax option
            textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
        }]       
    });
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Remove events will only remove the events that are visible, each time you move to a new month it will fetch the events for that month again and display them

Comment: Where do you store your events? It is better to remove them from database or whereever instead of not displaying them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove a subset of events, in this case we are filtering by an addition class name ('template') which was added to each event:

```
$myCal.fullCalendar( 'removeEvents', function( event ) {
     if( _.indexOf( event.className, 'template' ) > -1 ) {
          return true;
     }
     else {
          return false;
     }
} );
```

In your case I *think* each month change is reload from the given source.  One way I've avoid this behavior is to load the source outside of the calendar and then just inject the array.  For example:

```
var myCalEvents = fetchEvents(...);

// this is not reload with each change in calendar view 
$myCal.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', myCalEvents );
```

**Edit**

I would break the problem down.

First create a function to pull down each person's calendar

```
function getCalByPersonId( perId ) {
  // returns an array of fullcalender events pulled from the server
  // note each event will have a css class added by the name of
  // 'perid_x' where 'x' ist he perId parameter
  return ...{ajax call goes here}
}
```

Next create a function to handle the person change event.

```
function handlePersonChangeEvent( event ) {
  // first extract person id
  var perId = ... {code to get the person id}

  // clear any existing events for a previously selected person
  if( currentPerId && currentPerId !== perId ) {
    ...{remove code from above goes here, but replace 'template' with 'perId_x' where x is the currentPerId}
  }

  // add the new person's events to the calendar
  $myCal.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', function() {
    return getCalByPersonId( perId );
  } );

  // set the current person id
  currentPerId = perId;
}
```

I believe that will more or less do what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi I have a input (#name). Thats contains the employee value. For example i have two employees (A and B). The employee A has events in december.The employee B has events in January.so
                                                                1.The input value contains employee A and The month is december.Everithing is ok.
2.The input value contains employee B and The month is december.Everithing is ok.
3.If I change of month (next january).I obtain some employee A events.But I need that the calendar only shows employee B events.

thanks !!!